# cfselect onClick not calling javascript function

Tags: coldfusion

I have two mutually Exclusive OR cfselect with first option being blank (nothing selected).  When a non-blank option is selected in a cfselect, the blank option (first option) in another cfselect is selected with javascript function.  Yet, the javascript function is not called (tested with alert()) upon click an option.

```
function resetBusiness() {
  alert("resetBusiness() - Entering ..................."");

  var aForm = document.forms[0];
  var optDiv = aForm.getElementById("sDiv").value;

  alert("optDiv: |" + optDiv + "|");

  if (optDiv != "") {
    aForm.getElementById('sBus').selectedIndex  = 0;
    aForm.submit();
  }
}


function resetDivision() {
  alert("resetDivision() - Entering ..................."");

  var aForm = document.forms[0];
  var optBus  = aForm.getElementById("sBus").value;

  alert("optBus: |" + optBus + "|");

  if (optBus != "") {
    aForm.getElementById('sDiv').selectedIndex  = 0;
    aForm.submit();
  }
}
```

...

```
<cfselect id="sBus" name="sBus" query="qryBus" display="BU" value="BU"
          selected="#HDF(attributes.sBus)#" multiple="yes" size="6"
          queryPosition="below"
          onClick="javascript:resetDivision(this)">
  <option></option>
</cfselect>
```

Comment: Plus you are passing an argument to function that does not take one.

Answer (score 0):

@jbabey is right, you have too many quotes in your alert. Try changing to this:

```
alert("Entering resetDivision function...");
```

Also, it would be better to give your form an id too instead of using `document.forms[0]` in case you ever change your code and add another form above this one (like a search box at the top of the page). I've never seen `form.getElementById()`...

```
function resetDivision() {
  var optBus = document.getElementById("sBus").value;

  if (optBus != "") {
    document.getElementById('sDiv').selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("form1").submit();  // substitute with actual form id
  }
}
```

Your code also assumes that the elements exists. You can make your code more robust and only try to access a property of the object if it was fetched successfully:

```
var optBus = document.getElementById("sBus");
var optBusVal = '';
if (optBus && optBus != 'undefined') {  // actually I think you only need the first check
    optBusVal = optBus.value;
}
```